# fileupload doesn't work in server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, sqlexception

when i run this code on local host,its work currect but when upload on server show the error.

**code's :**

```
if (fUploadImg.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../Article/" + fUploadImg.FileName)))
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = "exist file";
                fImgName = fUploadImg.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                fUploadImg.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Article/" + fUploadImg.FileName));

                fImgName = fUploadImg.PostedFile.FileName;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = "error  " + err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        fImgName = "Article.png";
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cData.constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO tblArticle(aTitle,aText,aImg,aUrl,aDate,aDownlodable,aNote)VALUES(@title,@text,@imgN,@atachFn,@date,@down,@note)");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtArticleTitle.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", CKEditor1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgN", fImgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atachFn", fAtachName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", txtNote.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@down", rdoDownloadable.SelectedValue);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    clearObject();
```

**error :**
Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameterized query '`(@title nvarchar(3),@text nvarchar(3),@imgN nvarchar(4000),@atac`' expects the parameter '`@imgN`', which was not supplied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`: The parameterized query '`(@title nvarchar(3),@text nvarchar(3),@imgN nvarchar(4000),@atac`' expects the parameter '`@imgN`', which was not supplied.

Source Error:

```
Line 133:        

Line 134:        con.Open();

Line 135:        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Line 136:        con.Close();        

Line 137:        clearObject();
```

please help quickly.
**thanks.**

Comment: At a guess an error has occurred, hit the catch and finally block, fImgName is an empty string so its throwing an error on the database insert and you are not seeing ErrorMessage.Text.  Try commenting out the insert to the database and running on the server.  You will see the error.  Then reconstruct the code so it doesnt try to run the insert if its errored in the block above.

Comment: Pleas Check your Image folder path in Server.

Comment: i reconstruct the code an show this error : Access to the path 'D:\HostingSpaces\mysite.com\mysite.com\wwwroot\Article\title.png' is denied

Comment: @Fred,@user256103 what's your answer about this error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change the `..` to `~` in your codes to specify the root of the site.

  var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Article");
- Then contact your hosting provider and tell them your program needs a `write access` to the `Article` folders. It's not set by default.